# Command to get the id-port no: - & last three strings?

Tags: command

Can someone please help me with the one liner command to get the blocked and italicized only from running something like...ps -ef | grep java |  cut -d: -f20- | cut -d ' ' -f20 |

> Desired Result
>
> **wasadmin 15541  8868 tkin901Cell tkin901 tradeapp**

***wasadmin 15541  8868***  0 Mar12 ?        00:19:14 /a1/sys91/java/bin/java -Declipse.security -Dwas.status.socket=56259 -Dosgi.install.area=/u01/was85 -Dosgi.configuration.area=/a1/sys91/profiles/appsrv/servers/tradeapp/configuration -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dosgi.framework.extensions=com.ibm.cds,com.ibm.ws.eclipse.adaptors -Xshareclasses:name=webspherev85_1.6_64_%g,nonFatal -Dcom.ibm.xtq.processor.overrideSecureProcessing=true -Xbootclasspath/p:/a1/sys91/java/jre/lib/ibmorb.jar -classpath /a1/sys91/profiles/appsrv/properties:/a1/sys91/properties:/a1/sys91/lib/startup.jar:/a1/sys91/lib/bootstrap.jar:/a1/sys91/lib/jsf-nls.jar:/a1/sys91/lib/lmproxy.jar:/a1/sys91/lib/urlprotocols.jar:/a1/sys91/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar:/a1/sys91/deploytool/itp/batch2.jar:/a1/sys91/java/lib/tools.jar -Dibm.websphere.internalClassAccessMode=allow -verbose:gc -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Xcompressedrefs -Xscmaxaot4M -Xscmx90M -Dws.ext.dirs=/a1/sys91/java/lib:/a1/sys91/profiles/appsrv/classes:/a1/sys91/classes:/a1/sys91/lib:/a1/sys91/installedChannels:/a1/sys91/lib/ext:/a1/sys91/web/help:/a1/sys91/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime -Dderby.system.home=/a1/sys91/derby -Dcom.ibm.itp.location=/a1/sys91/bin -Djava.util.logging.configureByServer=true -Duser.install.root=/a1/sys91/profiles/appsrv -Djava.ext.dirs=/a1/sys91/tivoli/tam:/a1/sys91/java/jre/lib/ext -Djavax.management.builder.initial=com.ibm.ws.management.PlatformMBeanServerBuilder -Dpython.cachedir=/a1/sys91/profiles/appsrv/temp/cachedir -Dwas.install.root=/u01/was85 -Djava.util.logging.manager=com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WsLogManager -Dserver.root=/a1/sys91/profiles/appsrv -Dcom.ibm.security.jgss.debug=off -Dcom.ibm.security.krb5.Krb5Debug=off -Djava.library.path=/a1/sys91/lib/native/linux/x86_64/:/a1/sys91/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs:/a1/sys91/java/jre/lib/amd64:/a1/sys91/bin:/a1/sys91/nulldllsdir:/usr/lib: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/a1/sys91/endorsed_apis:/a1/sys91/java/jre/lib/endorsed -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/a1/sys91/profiles/appsrv/properties/wsjaas.conf -Djava.security.policy=/a1/sys91/profiles/appsrv/properties/server.policy com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher -nosplash -application com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer /a1/sys91/profiles/appsrv/config ***tkin901Cell tkin901 tradeapp***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data seems to be all in one line, then, to access the desired fields, you can use:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF}'
```

Comment: perfect thanks worked for me when I pipe this to java.